# How do I create a report that shows a graph of leads by inventory size?

Tags: reporting, salesforce-id

How do I create a report that shows a graph of leads by inventory size? I would like to know how many leads we have with an inventory of 1, 2, 3 etc or how many leads with inv. size between 1-10, 11-20 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create the Report on leads and Summarize information by: inventory at the Left top the report.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are capturing Inventory information, you may want to also leverage bucketing on reports where you are looking to grab a range of inventory sizes.

More details on how to use bucketing here: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_bucketing_adding.htm&language=en_US